# Updating a record using data from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a joining table that logs the changes in a File's state (Active/Deleted/Archived etc).

e.g.

```
+----+---------+------------+-------+
| PK | File_FK |    Date    | State |
+----+---------+------------+-------+
|  1 |     100 | 11-9-2015  |     1 |
|  2 |     200 | 14-09-2015 |     2 |
|  3 |     300 | 14-07-2015 |     0 |
|  4 |     300 | 12-9-2015  |     2 |
|  5 |     200 | 14-09-2015 |     2 |
|  6 |     300 | 14-09-2015 |     0 |
|  7 |     300 | 13-09-2015 |     1 |
+----+---------+------------+-------+
```

There are a number of records which are were not inserted accordingly, on a certain date e.g. July 15.

Is there a way how to automate the updating of certain records?

I want to change the state to the last option it was (latest date), if the state is 0 and if there are no previous 0 as states (for the same file foreign key) without amending previous states which had a zero.

To try and simplify (taking File_FK = 300 as example):

I want:

- The state of the file to update to be 1.
- State '0' is invalid since it was made on 14-09-2015 (the last one)
- Prevent updating the '0' that was made on 14-07-2015.
- Basically I want to change the state of a file to the state it was before it was '0' without changing the 0s that where done earlier.

Comment: can you add a sample output?

Comment: so i'm assuming by your differing date formats, that you're storing dates in varchar columns?  That's a big part of your problem :P

Comment: @Kritner Ahh no sorry.It's just how excel formatted them. They are of DateTime attribute type (all the same).

Comment: @DeepakPawar Output of what sorry?